# Can i get a hint for cutting-stock or bin-packing in python?

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming

I apologize for my poor English.
I've been assigned a project.
What I need to do appears to be some sort of "Cutting-stock" or "Bin-packing" algorithm. I've done a lot of searching on Google, but my problem seems to be too specific and complex.
To describe what I need to do
The inputs are a finite length and quantity of raw material and a length and quantity of processed material that needs to be made.

```
ex)
W_lengths = [10, 20, 30]
W_quantities = [5, 10, 15]
w_lengths = [5, 10, 15]
w_required_quantities = [30, 20, 10]
```

'W' represents the lengths and quantities of materials provided,
'w' represents the lengths and quantities you need to make from this material.
Also, the materials cannot be combined with each other, so for example, you cannot take 3 "W" of length 20 and make 4 "w" of length 15.

I want to make as little waste as possible in this process.
Is there a linear algorithm for solving this, or can I take a different approach? Any hints or pseudocode are welcome, and it doesn't have to be in Python!

I tried to do this using Python's pulp module.

Here's the code I created
However, in this case, I end up with three 20-long "w's" that I talked about earlier, and I end up with four 15-long "w's".
This is not the result I'm looking for, which is why I'm asking for your help.

```
import pulp

W = [6000, 6500, 7000, 7500, 8000, 8500, 9000, 10000, 11000, 12000]
Q = [20, 14, 50, 6, 300, 122, 15, 213, 22, 235]

w = [6000, 5300, 4700]
d = [4, 2, 2]

problem = pulp.LpProblem("CuttingStock", pulp.LpMinimize)


# y[i, j] represents how many times "W" piece i is used to produce "w" value j

x = [0] * len(W)
y = [[0] * len(w) for i in range(len(W))]
for i in range(len(W)):
    x[i] = pulp.LpVariable(f"x[{i}]", lowBound=0, cat=pulp.LpInteger)
    for j in range(len(w)):
        y[i][j] = pulp.LpVariable(
            f"y[{i}][{j}]", lowBound=0, cat=pulp.LpInteger)

# Define the objective function: Minimize waste
problem += pulp.lpSum(x[i] * W[i] - (pulp.lpSum(w[j] * y[i][j]) for j in range(len(w)))
                      for i in range(len(W)))

# Constraints: Cover all "w" values with selected "W" pieces
for j in range(len(w)):
    problem += pulp.lpSum(y[i][j] for i in range(len(W))) == d[j]

# Constraints: Ensure each "W" piece is used at most its quantity
for i in range(len(W)):
    problem += x[i] <= Q[i]

for i in range(len(W)):
    problem += (x[i] * W[i]) - pulp.lpSum(y[i][j] * w[j]
                                          for j in range(len(w))) >= 0
# Solve the problem
problem.solve()

problem.writeLP("out.txt")

# Print the optimal solution
if pulp.LpStatus[problem.status] == 'Optimal':
    for i in range(len(W)):
        if x[i].value() != 0:
            print(f"W{i}, used {x[i].value()}")
        for j in range(len(w)):
            if y[i][j].value() > 0:
                print(
                    f"w {j}, produced {y[i][j].value()}")
    used = 0
    for i in range(len(W)):
        used += x[i].value() * W[i]
    print(used)
    if problem.objective.value() != 0:
        print(
            f"Final loss: {problem.objective.value()}\nLoss%: {(used / problem.objective.value()) * 100}%")
    else:
        print("No loss")
else:
    print("No optimal solution found.")
```

Comment: This sounds like a variation/reframing of the Knapsack problem, that might be a good starting point for further research (I don't think there is a linear time solution, I would guess that an LP solver like you are using is one of the fastest solutions you will find)

Comment: You've got nothing in your code preventing the materials from being combined, aka using 2 W of size 15 to produce 3 w of size 10.

Comment: How fixed are these inputs? Are these specific inputs (6000, etc.) the only ones that need to be solved for, or is the attempt to solve the problem generally? Will every `W` >= every `w` always? Will every `Q` >= every `d` always?